# Windows universal C++ concurrency

Tags: concurrency, win-universal-app, c++-cx

I have the following pattern:

```
task<Param1^> MyClass::MethodA(String^ s)
{
     return create_task([this, s]
     {

         ....

         IAsyncOperation<Param1^>^ result = SystemMethod1ReturningParam1(...);

         return result;
     });
}

IAsyncOperation<Param2^>^ MyClass::MethodB(String^ s)
{
    return create_async([this, s]
    {
         return MethodA(s).then([this](task<Param1^> t)
         {
             Param1^ p1 = t.get();

             ....

             Param2^ result = SystemMethod2ReturningParam2(p1);
             return result ;
         });
    });
}
```

I call public MethodB which calls private MethodA. Param1 is standard enum that I cannot change. MethodA create_task my need to return error condition. I cannot return null. MethodB also needs return error condition.

What's the best way to return errors from both methods?

SystemMethod1ReturningParam1 and SystemMethod2ReturningParam2 which are framework system methods can throw exceptions. Where do I catch them?

Comment: I hate to say it but learning C++ or concurency by WinRT is a bad practice. try understand it by using the standard first..

Comment: I am very proficient in classic C++ and classic concurrency.

Comment: Just [rtfm first](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997692.aspx), then ask a focused question that shows you trying to use what is there.

Comment: That code for sure is not C++. It looks like something called C++/CLI, which is a whole different beast.

Answer (score 0):

If you are worried about exceptions, you should always use task-based continuations and wrap the call to `task.get()` in a `try/catch`.

Note that the code below (and other C++ code) throws `std::exception`, but if you are interfacing with WinRT components and you want the exception to propagate, you must re-throw as a `Platform::Exception` value.

```
concurrency::task<int> throw_async()
{
  return concurrency::create_task([]
  {
    throw std::exception("oops");
    return -1;
  });
}

void test_value()
{
  // This will crash inside PPL runtime due to unobserved exception
  throw_async().then([](int x)
  {
    OutputDebugString(L"You'll never see this\r\n");
  });
}

void test_task()
{
  // This will handle the exception correctly
  throw_async().then([](concurrency::task<int>& t)
  {
    OutputDebugString(L"You'll see this\r\n");
    try
    {
      auto val = t.get();
      OutputDebugString(L"You'll never see this\r\n");
    }
    catch (std::exception& ex)
    {
      auto error = ex.what(); // "oops"
      // Need to re-throw if this crosses the WinRT ABI boundary.
      // Conversion of 'error' to Platform::String^ omitted for brevity
      throw ref new Platform::FailureException(/* error */);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: It does not seem to work this way. If I throw std::exception I catch Pltform::exception with E_FAIL and "Unspecified error" as description when I try to access task.get.